# Stop the execution of a macro using another macro(button) using the sendKeys function

Tags: vba, excel

I have this Vba code that takes a lot of time to execute and i did this `sub` to stop the execution, But it didnt work , i used the `Sendkeys` function.

```
sub stop ()
SendKeys "{Ctrl,Pause}"
end sub
```

i want also to resume the execution of my Macro, i tried clicking Ctrl+Break but it didnt resume.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: you need to manually hit the CTRL + BREAK to stop the execution.

Comment: So there is no way to stop the execution using another Macro ?

Comment: why would you want to stop execution of a macro by using another macro? That sounds very twisted

Comment: Well like i said i have this `Code` in vba that runs for days , i just want to pause it for a moment to see what it's doing,And i need to check very often now because i changed it

Comment: You want to pause or stop(terminate)? If you want to pause to see what is going on use `Debug.Assert`

Comment: If im not wrong That's just to check the conditions

Comment: `Debug.Assert` and a `condition` that evaluates to `false` allows to `pause` the macro not terminate its execution. It goes into the debug mode and allows you to see *what it's doing*. You can then use the watch and locals windows to see currently underlying values of variables etc.

Comment: Alright , im going to check the `Debug.Assert` function , thank you by the way

Comment: Just tested `Debug.Assert` loved it i had some uncleard things in my new programme(Another one),im going to start to use it.
**BUT** it dosn't answer my question

Comment: Ok, I can still give you an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open VBE and insert a module and copy-paste the below code

```
Sub Main()
    For i = 1 To 100000
        DoEvents
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub

Sub PauseMacro()
    Application.SendKeys "^{BREAK}"
End Sub
```

Go back to Sheet1 and on the developer tab insert a button and assign the `PauseMacro` to it.

Now run the `Main` sub and hit the button to stop the execution of the `Main` macro

Oh, btw. [here's how to use the `Application.SendKeys` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `SendKeys`.

An approach similar to the one suggested by me how, but without using SendKeys could be this:

```
Global IsTimeToStop As Boolean

Sub Main()
    IsTimeToStop = False
    For i = 1 To 100000
        DoEvents
        Debug.Print i
        If IsTimeToStop Then Exit Sub
    Next i
End Sub

Sub PauseMacro()
    IsTimeToStop = True
End Sub
```

Replace `Global` with `Dim` if this is not a standard module.

Comment: Im going to try your solution (i like it ) and see what it does,Thank you by the way

Answer (score 2):

What about setting up a watch on a variable that breaks if it changes?

just right click on a variable and add a new watch.

[image: VBA Watch]

Comment: its like the `Debug.Assert` function what do you mean by **that breaks if it changes**

Comment: @Awsome33 the code execution will pause (as if it hit a break point) if the value of the variable changes value.